# Have trouble build firefox 60.9esr

Tags: firefox, rust, debian

I have already tried a lot of ways to build firefox 60.9. I have tried to build it on debian 10(buster) 12(bookworm) ubuntu18.04(bionic beaver). But when it runs to "compile" step during building process, It always exits with error: https://paste.mozilla.org/qPH9Dyod. It seems failed to build cssparser with no reason, but I have no way to debug. It confuse me a lot. Thanks.

tried to build on debian 10(buster) 12(bookworm) ubuntu18.04(bionic beaver) with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use rustc 1.32 and the problem fixed on debian 10(buster). The building process successfully finished! But on debian 12(bookworm) there is something wrong, I think the gcc version is too high and I will try a lower version of it.

But it's strange that the rust code of firefox 60.9esr can only built under rustc 1.32.